# React-native application giving white screen while running the project for the first time

Tags: android, react-native

I have setup a react-native application by running **react-native run-android** and tried running it with **react-native start**. Packager gives no error but the app getting stuck on a white screen . I have tried it on my mobile device and on simulator as well but all ended up in failure. Also I have cross checked the host IP in device developer settings. 
When I tried running `http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` in google chrome, I got `{"type":"InternalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}` 
I have shell out lots of time into this but find nothing. There were some links related to white screen issue but those were some code issue related to external modules they were using, but mine is just a vanilla react native project with nothing being added.

React-native version **0.46.4**
Platform **macOS Sierra version 10.12.2**

Have tried running `gradle clean` and also deleted the build folder before **react-native run-android**.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue,And was able to solve this by changing my **package.json** file on my machine.

Update the script in package.json by changing `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start` to `node_modules/react-native/scripts/packager.sh` this will allow your android emulator to read the index.andriod.js file from your local machine.

Also use **npm start** to run the dev server.

I am not sure why this is causing this, but it can be read issue from the dev server from android emulator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe because the package signatures don't match with the already installed version on your device. Uninstall and run again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Getting this issue whenever I ran the application first time after installation. Just exit the application, clear it from RAM and open again. Hurray! the issue is resolved.